# Pomelo / Docker / MySQL - Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: docker, .net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am trying to use EF-Core, code first, I have built my migrations, and run them, with no problem (they have worked).

However, when I try to call the context to save the changes, I am getting the following error:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Obviously, this is a strange error, with the fact the migrations work, however I am wondering if this has something to do with MySQL running in Docker and the application running in Docker?

Context:

```
public class TextContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql("Server=127.0.0.1; Port=3306; Database=Test; Uid=root; Pwd=password;");
    }
}
```

Calling Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var _context = new TextContext())
            {
                _context.People.Add(this);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Call:

```
public string CreatePerson()
{
    Person person = new Person();
    person.FirstName = "Phil";
    person.LastName = "Regan";
    person.Job = new Job() { JobTitle = "Developer", Salary = 123.12} ;
    person.Save();

    return "done";
}
```

Docker is set to allow connections from 3306 and I am able to run migrations from pm console, and able to connect via HeidiSQL - Any advice welcomed.

Comment: Can you add the information about how you are bringing up the docker containers?

Comment: docker run -p 3306:3306 --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql:latest

Comment: The .net core part is just using, create fo docker, and when I run, it runs in a pod.

Comment: In that case you should use container IP in your application (assuming both the containers are in the same network) instead of 127.0.0.1. You can get container IP by checking `docker inspect some-mysql`

Comment: @akazuko thank you - that works, is there a way to connect to the mysql via some sort of name - so when I move this to a production server, settings can persist etc?

Comment: yeah, you can use docker-compose to achieve that. In that case you can use the container name to reach the container directly.

Comment: Our [azure-pipelines.yml](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml) YAML script to run all the Pomelo test on our CI environment uses docker (for the Linux environment). Take a look at it, if you want to compare or need some inspiration.